# Why am I getting "Too many connections" error?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm running a script that runs a function in parallel using `concurrent.futures`. The script uses the following access layer:

```
class DataAccessLayer():

    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = create_engine(CONN_STRING, pool_size=95, max_overflow=0)
        self.connection = self.engine.connect()


class DataAccessLayerParallel(DataAccessLayer):

    def __init__(self):
        DataAccessLayer.__init__(self)
        session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=self.connection)
        Session = scoped_session(session_factory)
        self.session = Session()
```

And the parallel running is handled by:

```
def my_func():
    dal = DataAccessLayerParallel()
    # Some data operations...
    dal.session.commit()
    dal.session.close()
    dal.connection.close()

with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
   executor.map(my_func)
```

The `my.ini` file has the configuration `max_connections=100` however I keep getting the error:

```
Exception has occurred: DatabaseError
(mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError) 1040: Too many connections
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the MySQL server?

Comment: @snakecharmerb - yes :-) Since I posted I've been keeping tabs on the number of connections via MySQL and it does seem to be proportional to the limit I set on the `pool_size`, i.e. if I set it to 200 then it gets up to around 300 but if I set it to 100 then it doesn't usually get above 200. As this isn't a production db with lots of users then I guess I can just set the `my.ini` file to a level significantly above `pool_size` and I shouldn't hit the limits again.